# Computing Gini index in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, gini

I'm trying to write down the gini index calculation as a tensorflow cost function. Gini index is:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient

a numpy solution would be

```
def ginic(actual, pred):
    n = len(actual)
    a_s = actual[np.argsort(pred)]
    a_c = a_s.cumsum()
    giniSum = a_c.sum() / a_s.sum() - (n + 1) / 2.0
    return giniSum / n
```

Can someone help me figure out how to do this in tf (for example, in tf there is no argsort that can be part of a  function that is differentiated, AFAIK)

Comment: There is an implementation of a differentiable sort operator, a pretty recent research result also available in TF https://github.com/google-research/fast-soft-sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform the argsorting by using [`tf.nn.top_k()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/top_k). This function returns a tuple, the second element being the indices. Its order must be reversed since the order is descending.

```
def ginicTF(actual:tf.Tensor,pred:tf.Tensor):
    n = int(actual.get_shape()[-1])
    inds =  tf.reverse(tf.nn.top_k(pred,n)[1],axis=[0]) # this is the equivalent of np.argsort
    a_s = tf.gather(actual,inds) # this is the equivalent of numpy indexing
    a_c = tf.cumsum(a_s)
    giniSum = tf.reduce_sum(a_c)/tf.reduce_sum(a_s) - (n+1)/2.0
    return giniSum / n
```

Here is a code you can use for verification that this function returns the same numerical value as your numpy function `ginic`:

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
ac = tf.placeholder(shape=(50,),dtype=tf.float32)
pr = tf.placeholder(shape=(50,),dtype=tf.float32)
actual  = np.random.normal(size=(50,))
pred  = np.random.normal(size=(50,))
print('numpy version: {:.4f}'.format(ginic(actual,pred)))
print('tensorflow version: {:.4f}'.format(ginicTF(ac,pr).eval(feed_dict={ac:actual,pr:pred})))
```

Comment: Ok, this looks good but when passed to a NN as a loss function it returns an error

for line: ---> 14     n = int(actual.get_shape()[-1])

error:     TypeError: \__int\__ returned non-int (type NoneType)

It does work as expected if I just run a session

Comment: I think this happens because the shape of your placeholder\tensor for `actual` is `(None,)`, which means that it doesn't have a pre-defined length, thus `n` cannot be computed at the time of graph construction. In that case, what you can do is just pass `n` (the length of the arrays) as an additional argument to the function, instead of computing it.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't able to resolve this (tried giving default value of n, but this does not solve it). I made a new question for this particular problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46674293/custom-loss-function-in-keras-how-to-deal-with-placeholders 

Again, thank you for writing down the function in TF!